# Why is Typescript variable length not found?

Tags: javascript, angular

In an Angular 5 project, I have the following in:

inventory.component.ts:

```
  inventoryItems: any;
  constructor(private router: Router,) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.inventoryItems=[];
  }
```

I reference the variable like this in `inventory.component.html`:

```
<span class="indicator">{{inventoryItems.length}}</span>
```

The browser console is complaining about:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

If the property is getting initialized in ngOnInit, why would it be null? It should be zero.

Comment: Why not set it as an empty array in the component definition?

Comment: If `this.inventoryItems` is an `observable`, then you could try doing `{{ 
 inventoryItems.length | async }}` within the HTML. This will tell the template to wait until the `observable` is resolved.

Comment: Put it inside constructor `this.inventoryItems=[];`

Comment: I don't think the OP is asking for a fix. The question appears to be more about why `ngOnInit` is not running before the template first attempts to access `inventoryItems`.

Comment: The code in the question doesn't explain why `inventoryItems` is null. Because it won't be null, and the code above won't throw an error. If it's an input, this should be reflected in the question. Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can be replicated.

Comment: Something else must be the problem because even if the template was trying to access the value of inventoryItems, before the ngOnInit ran, the error would be:  Cannot read property 'length' of undefined, not null. You must be specifically assigning it the value of null somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding  **`*ngIf="inventoryItems"`**

```
<span *ngIf="inventoryItems" class="indicator">{{inventoryItems.length}}</span>
```

Comment: This worked and the error is gone. But I don't see any output for length. It should be "0". Any idea why it isn't show anything?

Answer (score 1):

it is `null` on first template initialization, because `ngOnInit` is called after calling first `ngOnChanges`, which sets the props initially.
[check docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

you can implemet `OnChanges` (and handle all props input changes manually), or you can set default value like this for example `inventoryItems: any[] = [];`